# $http get request successful but not displayed in view

Tags: angularjs, http, view, controller, request

I'm using Angular's $http.get(..) using an API from google Books API. I wanted the input field to store user's input which can be stored in the query string : '/q=/key=....'

When I submit the search field, the request is successful, but the information isn't shown. I've been working on this for a while and still stuck. Could it be my controller? or how i set up the request? 
The result is just this:
[image]

Here's the code.

```
app.controller("HomeController", ['$scope', '$location', 'bookSearch',function($scope, $location, bookSearch){
$scope.website="CoolMark";
$scope.books= '';
$scope.submit= function () {
    if($scope.books === ''){
        alert('Field is empty');
        console.log('not working');
        return false;
    } else {

        $location.path('/search');
        bookSearch($scope.books).success(function(data){
        $scope.searchResult= data;
        }); 
        console.log(typeof $scope.books);

    }
};
}]);
```

now for the service...

```
app.factory('bookSearch', ['$http', function($http){
    return function(info){
       return $http.get('https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q='+info+'&orderBy=relevance&filter=ebooks&key=AIzaSyCpWB1q0-kqFEH9f5Sh8xUrXfrhoxAG7wk')
        .success(function(data){
            return data;
        })
        .error(function(err){
            return err;
        });
    };
}]);
```

Any suggestion how to improve this code? As for the view, here it is:

```
<div class="feature">
  <div class="container">
    <h3>Return Home</h3>
    <h2 class="text-center">Your Results for: "{{books}}"</h2>
    <div class="book_content">
       <div ng-repeat="item in searchResult.items" id="book-item">
            <img ng-src="{{item.volumeInfo.imageLinks['thumbnail']}}" alt="">
                <h5>{{item.volumeInfo.title}}</h5>
                <p>{{}}</p>
       </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: try removing the `.success and .error` handler in your factory

Comment: nothing happened to the view. i think it's the view that needs to change?

Comment: can you post the data that is returned from the request? I created a plunker,  not exactly similar to what you have but take a look http://plnkr.co/edit/nrF4JIoAr3DfGKalUXuH?p=preview

Comment: I updated a photo of the result is empty, nothing. Well nothing's wrong with what i put in the view except the request. maybe it's my controller or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pass `$timeout` to the controller:

```
app.controller("HomeController", 
    ['$scope', '$location', '$timeout', 'bookSearch',
      function($scope, $location, $timeout, bookSearch) {
```

and do

```
$timeout(function() {
    $scope.searchResult= data;
});
```

Many asynchronous updates happen outside the digest cycle.  The $timeout() makes the update wait until the next digest cycle so that angular sees the change and updates the view.

UPDATE: Update to the factory code:

```
app.factory('bookSearch', ['$http', function($http){
    var factory = {}
    factory.getBooks = function(info){
       return $http.get('[your url]')
    };
    return factory;
}]);
```

then do your search:

```
bookSearch.getBooks($scope.books).success(function(data){ ...
```

Comment: I'm not sure whether i did it right according to your input or that it still doesn't show up hmm.... I basically did this: 
bookSearch($scope.books).success(function(data){
        $timeout(function() {
            $scope.searchResult= data;
             });
        }); 

Don't know if that's correct.

Comment: hmm.  Are you getting any errors in the console?  $timeout has to be passed to the controller.  I'll update the answer to show it

Comment: it'd be nice to show you with pictures but i tried it another way without $timeout. Now the $scope.books doesn't update the q= in the request whenever a user search something. the console says 400 it's missing a text string. I did use the ng-model= 'books' and pass it in the bookSearch($scope.books) but the console says nothing  attached to q= ; if i were to type bookSearch('Harry Potter') and not the search from the model it'd work. weird... :)

Comment: Try updating your factory as above.  I believe that a factory should return an object and a service should return a function (if I'm not misremembering)

Comment: Maybe if you give more of your html, we can build a fiddle and find out where the problem is

Comment: [Here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/beartums/arb3km4s/2/) using your original code and it seems to be working (I just set the search text internally and call the submit).  It seems to be working as far as I can tell...

Comment: i check your fiddle and it does appear to work but when i type in the search field, it doesn't change or show new request. it stays as harry

Comment: give me a sec i'll put all the info in js fiddle

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101838/discussion-between-h-fall-and-beartums).

Comment: If you don't mind checking the gist it's not all the files but just the ones including home.html which contains the search form. I think you'll see what i mean. thanks for your help and time :) https://gist.github.com/hfall/ae7e90bcec493a512bb5

Comment: @H.fall, I moved to chat